# Ubermenu cant handle my menu, how to deal with large number of menuitems?

Tags: menus

I have a webpage with a large number of pages, around 250-300, and I output these in Ubermenu at the moment. Needles to say, my menu backend is very slow, and sorting is a pain in the.. well you know. Is there any other good way to deal with such large numbers of menuitems? Any suggestion would be appriciated!

Comment: Why does your menu have so many items? Perhaps archives would be more appropriate? What's an Ubermenu?

Comment: I have an rss aggregated site, and each rssfeed has it own page. Ubermenu is a plugin to handle more items.. This is the site: skatevids.me

Comment: That menu is massive. If you don't have a big enough monitor you are not even able to see all menu items. Use an archive page, sort it out by categories, brands, alphabetically, date... that will make way easier to find content than having someone trying to navigate this menu.

Comment: Well, at the moment its that way yeah. Not an answer to my question though..